# Android SqlLite check if two values exist in 2 different columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an application where the user inputs title and the date. I want to prevent the duplicated titles being inputted on the same day in to database. I am checking if the title exists on the selected date. However my query seems not to work and i don't know why, the application just crashes.Is this query correct? Can someone help?

```
public boolean checkExist(String title, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TITLE+"=?" +"AND" + DATE+"=?", new String[] {title,date});
    boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, How? Does it fail or does the cursor return no data (i.e. checkExist always returns false)? If it fails then include the log. If it returns do data then I'd suggest putting a breakpoint at `boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();` then from the debugger have a look at the cursor. especially the generated query.

Comment: the application crashes

Comment: please include the logcat. Ooops sorry missed that you had said that it crashes. Uhhm at a guess it's a message along the lines of INDEX 1 from 0 rows because the cursor has no rows and you are trying to move. You should check the number of rows in the cursor using c.getCount() and return true if greater than 0, else false.

Comment: is the query correct ?

Comment: `boolean exists = cursor.getCount() > 0`

Comment: i did that still crashes

Comment: It would help us if you provided the actual reason your app crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue that you have is that `c.moveToFirst` will always fail if a match does not exist as you are trying to move to a row in an empty cursor.

The resolution is to not use `c.moveToFirst` and instead get the count of the rows and then set the return value accordingly.

e.g.

```
public boolean checkExist(String title, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TITLE+"=?" +"AND" + DATE+"=?", new String[] {title,date});
    boolean exists = c.getCount() > 0;
    c.close();
    return exists;
}
```

The second issue is that the query itself is wrong as you do not have spaces either side of the **AND** keyword. That is instead of

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TITLE+"=?" +"AND" + DATE+"=?", new String[] {title,date});
```

You should have

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TITLE+"=?" +" AND " + DATE+"=?", new String[] {title,date});
```

*Personally, I setup constants for SQL keywords that include the space and then use these. So I'd have something along the lines of `+TITLE+"=?" + SQLAND + DATE+"=?"`. Where SQLAND would be defined along the lines of `String SQLAND=" AND ";`*

PS look at Cricket_007's answer, the code is neater/better it's easier to read.

Comment: Your spacing is also off

Comment: [queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) would be simpler.

Comment: whatever i do it just keeps crushing

Comment: You will have to edit your question and include the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing is off. `TITLE+"=?" +"AND" + DATE` becomes `TITLE=?ANDDATE=?`

I would suggest this. See [`DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

```
public boolean checkExist(String title, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String[] args = new String[] {title,date};
    String filter = String.format("%s=? AND %s=?", TITLE, DATE);

    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME, filter, args) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should be using c.getCount() instead of c.moveToFirst()

if the value is greater than 0, then it exists

Comment: love it when people take your answer, re-post it with some more verbiage, then downvote your answer.